# key error value 0 on modelformset when queryset is empty

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i want to create multiple instances of a model using a modelformset.
but when the queryset is empty and the parameter `extra` is greater than 0 it raises this error:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/alta_socies/proces_alta_projecte_autoocupat/adreces/

Django Version: 1.7.7
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.formtools',
'inici',
'alta_socies',
'empreses',
'socies')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/usergci/gestioci/alta_socies/templates/alta_socies/proces_alta_autoocupat.html, error at line 59
   0
   49 :     <div class="row">


   50 :         <div class="medium-12 columns content">


   51 :             <div class="row">


   52 :                 <div class="medium-12 columns">


   53 :                     <div class="group">


   54 :                         <h2>{{ projecte.pas }}</h2>


   55 :                         {% block explicacio_pas %}{% endblock %}


   56 :                     </div>


   57 :                     <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}


   58 :                     {{ wizard.management_form }}


   59 :                      {% if wizard.form.forms %}


   60 :                             {{ wizard.form.management_form }}


   61 :                         {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}


   62 :                             {% block step_factory_form %}


   63 :                             {% endblock %}


   64 :                         {% endfor %}


   65 :                     {% else %}


   66 :                         {% block step_single_form %}


   67 :                         {% endblock %}


   68 :                     {% endif %}


   69 :                     <input class="small radius button" type="submit" name="save_only" value="Guardar y salir"/>


Traceback:
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  80.         content = template.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  402.         return strip_spaces_between_tags(self.nodelist.render(context).strip())
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  305.                     match = condition.eval(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in eval
  898.         return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  596.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  734.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  770.                         current = getattr(current, bit)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  55.         res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in forms
  141.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in xrange(self.total_form_count())]
File "/home/usergci/.virtualenvs/heteroceras/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  591.                 kwargs['initial'] = self.initial_extra[i - self.initial_form_count()]

Exception Type: KeyError at /alta_socies/proces_alta_projecte_autoocupat/adreces/
Exception Value: 0
```

the offending lines as far as i debugged are:

```
    AdrecesFormSet = modelformset_factory(AdrecaProjecteAutoocupat,
                                      form=FormulariAdrecaProjecteAutoocupat,
                                      can_delete=True)
```

any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wizard form was expecting a list of dicts intead of a dict!!! The problem was somewhere else in the views.py